# How can I count all elements in a DXL skip list

Tags: ibm-doors

I am trying to count all elements within a `Skip` list without having to know the type of the element contained within it.

like this:

```cpp
Module mod = current()
Skip skip = create()

put(skip, 1, "test")
put(skip, 2, mod)

print count(skip) // Returns integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `DOORS` does not support this natively. To create this functionality I took advantage of an odd loop behavior *where the object in a loop doesn't get assigned until you actually use it*:

```cpp
int count(Skip skip)
{
    if(null skip)
        return 0

    int i = 0

    // Doesn't get assigned unless you do something like obj = obj within the loop
    string obj = null 

    for obj in skip do
    {
        i++
    }

    return i
}
```